# Assigning a java variable string value with double quotes to input hidden field on jsp

Tags: javascript, scriptlet

I am trying to assign a value to hindden input field. But string which I am assigning contains double quotes, so input hidden field is not considering the entire value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="strWithDoubleQuotes" value="<%=strDQ%>">
<script>
var stringValue = '<%=strDQ%>';
alert(stringValue);
</script>
```

stringValue prints following text:
This is a the test string "The test String" data.

However when I do: document.getElementById('strWithDoubleQuotes').value , I get output as 'This is a the test string '.

Please help me with this.
I need the entire string value in hidden input field

Comment: try using value='<%=strDQ%>'

Comment: Java != javascript this is clearly "just" javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="strWithDoubleQuotes" value='<%=strDQ%>'>
<script>
var stringValue = '<%=strDQ%>';
alert(stringValue);
</script>
```

Comment: It is better to explain your code when you give an answer